# using glDrawPixels to render bitmap raw data

Tags: qt, opengl, qt4, qt5

I receive raw image data from server. The server uses MS Dib() function which returns in BGR format. Now, what i want to do is to read this raw data and use glDrawPixels to draw it in Linux.
I was advised that GetClrTabAddress function in MS and alike shall be used to get me the RGB values for each index of 800 by 600 image sent to me.
I do not know how to get these values using indices. Could anyone give some tips.

```
void func(QByteArray)
{
    window_width  = 800;
    window_height = 600;
    size = window_width * window_height;
    pixels = new float[size*3];
    memcpy(pixels, bytes, bytes.size());
}

void GlWidget::paintGL()
{
    //! [5]
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDrawPixels(window_width,window_height,GL_RGB,GL_FLOAT,pixels);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GL_BGR` in `glDrawPixels`, which will do the conversion for you and will probably be faster since AFAIK the GPU will do the work.

`QByteArray` sounds like you should be using unsigned bytes/`char`s instead of `float`s, which means `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`.

I'd `assert(size*3*sizeof(float) == bytes.size());`.

In this case make sure to set `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)` if your width doesn't align to the default 4-byte boundry. With GL_BGR very pixel is 3 bytes and by default each row of your pixels is assumed to be padded to the next 4-byte boundary.

*[EDIT]*
OK, it looks like the image uses a palette. This means every value inthe QByteArray maps to an rgb value in another array. I'm not 100% sure where the palette is and maybe it can be computed implicitly, but you mentioned `GetClrTabAddress` which sounds promising.

The code will then look something like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    unsigned char index = btmp[i];
    //and something like..
    memcpy(bytes + i * 3, GetClrTabAddress() + index * 3, 3);
    //or
    bytes[i*3+0] = someOtherPaletteData[index].red;
    bytes[i*3+1] = someOtherPaletteData[index].green;
    bytes[i*3+2] = someOtherPaletteData[index].blue;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, it was somehow useful, but it is not completely the solution, have a look at your post, I edited the below part.

Comment: @user1596226 ok, makes a bit more sense now.

Comment: thanks for the idea, though the problem i have is that I have no idea what the palette data is and don know how to map indices to which palete array!

Comment: @user1596226 Have a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Color_table. Do you have a library that loads the image for you? It should provide the table and you can use the `memcpy` line above (may need to adjust `index * 3` depending on the data type). If not, finding one would be a good idea. Or follow the wiki page to unpack the data yourself.